# I can't do inner join in Codeigniter and combine with where condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to join two tables projects and events_projects , i have column relation in table events_projects which have number of project id. I want ot get events which relate to this project. In view i have one project and timeline with events which relate ti this project. I tried to do this inner join, but i get just one event of this project, but in database i have few events of this project. How can i get all events of project?

This if my function in Model:

```
 public function getProject($id){
        $this->db->select('projects.*, events_projects.*');
        $this->db->from('projects');
        $this->db->where('projects.project_id', $id);
        $this->db->join('events_projects', 'projects.project_id = events_projects.relation', 'inner');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $project = $query->result_array()[0];
        return $project;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused, you said you want to get the project events, but the query you provide is to get a project

Comment: i want ot get one project and events of this project with one query.Events maybe few, but at this moment my query get project and one of events of this project bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$this->db->from('projects')` with `$this->db->from('events_projects')` :

```
public function getProject($id){
    $this->db->select('projects.*, events_projects.*');
    $this->db->from('events_projects');
    $this->db->join('projects', 'projects.project_id = events_projects.relation', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('projects.project_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $project = $query->result_array()[0];
    return $project;
}
```